# How to connect unix server with credentials and execute commands from python script

Tags: python, paramiko

i am new to python scripting can someone please assist belo

1.read server, username and password
2.connect unix server
3.change directory and execute command

need some examples for above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the excellent [paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/) package for this.  It is an SSH (and SFTP) client library, which will let you easily connect to a Unix server running an ssh service, run commands, transfer files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org). Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.